# fprintf not working the way I want it to

Tags: c, file, printf

```
void fileOpen(char * fname)
{
    FILE *txt, *newTxt;
    char line[256];
    char fileName[256];

    txt = fopen(fname, "r");    
    if(txt == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    newTxt = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if(newTxt == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //Problem is in the while loop
    while(fgets(line, 256, txt) != NULL)
    {
        if (strncmp(line, "#include", 7) == 0)
        {   
            strcpy(fileName, extractSubstring(line));
            fileOpen(fileName);
        }

        else
            fprintf(newTxt, "%s", line); <---- It just prints over itself
    }

    fcloseall();
}
```

The point of the program is recursive file extraction. Every time it sees #include at the start of the line, it prints out the contents of the file.

For some reason in every line, the variable "line" just writes over itself. Instead, I want it to  rather than printout to a file.. then in a new line printing out the new line. Am I using it correctly?

Example: I use a command line argument `yo.txt` which is passed to `void fileOpen(char *fname)`.

In `yo.txt`:

```
Hello stackoverflow.
#include "hi.txt"
Thank you!
```

In `hi.txt`:

```
Please help me.
```

Expected final result:

```
Hello stackoverflow.
Please help me
Thank you!
```

Comment: Add a `'\n'` to the `fprintf` perhaps?

Comment: `perror( fname )`, `perror( fname )`, `perror( fname )`!!!!!  If I ever see another error message that fails to tell me the name of the file to which the message applies, I will scream.

Comment: You are opening `output.txt` in mode `w`.  Each time you do that, you truncate (discard) everything previously written.

Comment: Well, for starters, "#include" is 8 characters.

Comment: What about circular references? (The pinnacle of which is a file 'x' that starts with `include "x"`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you move to the next level i.e.

```
strcpy(fileName, extractSubstring(line));
fileOpen(fileName);
```

you open the same output file again,

```
newTxt = fopen("output.txt", "w");
```

Instead pass the file pointer to the output file as a function argument to fileOpen. Before you open the first file you should open the output file and pass it to fileOpen.

```
 void fileOpen(char * fname, FILE* output)
```

Comment: Why not simply `fopen("output.txt", "a");`? Should do the trick (though the file would have to be wiped somewhere before the recursive calls).

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks. I make another function that returned a FILE to specifically open the file. 

I have one more problem. fcloseall() closes all the files before it is finished reading (on the recursive stack). 

Can I just use that command in the main function? Will it still close the files in the other functions?

Comment: @juice: why not just *close* the file that you *open* inside the function? On Windows, at least, there is a maximum to the number of "open files" you can have (which would be a problem, by the way, with deep recursion).